# Could anyone help me to analyze this diagram precisely, like a full explaination?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diagram

Here, I have finished a project and the concept is that(You can also go to the link below to watch the project video),

we have a LED light(yellow L1) that blinks really fast when we run the circuit. We have 10 lights that flow sequentially fast when we hold the switch and stop when we release the switch. It is like a reaction game where user attempt to hit the last light(10th) to win. If the user hit any of the light(e.g 8th light), the 8th light will be turned on until the user plays the game again.

**I have questions in my mind,**

**1.** Why the first LED light blinks so fast? What makes it to blink that fast?

**2.** How do the other 10 LED(red) turn on and off sequentially? is it the cause of the 4017IC?

**3.** What is the major use of this 555 timer IC? What if we didn't use that

**4.** What is the importance of C2 and C3 capacitor? Why we need them?

**5.** How the LED remained turned on until we press the switch again?

I hope someone will come up with a precise explanation. I will appreciate it a lot
I have uploaded a video of this project
[Video link youtube](https://youtube.com/shorts/EwMQ0_RuVTQ?feature=share)

I have created a precise circuit diagram for understanding.
[image: Circuit]

Comment: We don't do homewrk questions without a significant effort at an answer from you.  Afterall all what do you learn if someone does the thinking for you.

Comment: It is not a homework. Its just a project that I built and want to learn

Comment: Study the datasheets for the 555 timer and the 4017 counter - they should explain the operation of the ICs.

Answer (score 1):

1. The first LED blinks at the clock rate of the 555 timer oscillator
2. The 4017 is a sequential [Johnson decade counter](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/n-bit-johnson-counter-in-digital-logic/)
3. The 555 is a convenient and popular timer IC configured as an oscillator, with a frequency determined by the R-C time constant on the trigger, threshold, and discharge pins. Other clock sources could be used.
4. C2 is a bypass for the 555's control voltage, which is determined by the voltage divider in the chip. It helps stabilize it and reduces noise. C3 is a power supply bypass which helps provide a low impedance current source for the 555 and 4017 digital circuits.
5. Releasing the switch disconnects the clock from the 4017 counter.

To help you learn, answer the following:

1. Calculate the oscillator frequency
2. Calculate the current for the LEDs
3. Determine the control voltage on pin 5

Comment: If you have any good resource to learn for solving ur questions could you share? specially 1 and 3?

Comment: Google is your friend: https://www.eleccircuit.com/555-timer-circuit-works/